# Formatting error reporting

Tags: python-2.7

I am logging all errors to a file, since there is no other way to see them properly in my case, especially in prod environment. Like this:

```
sys.stderr = open('py/log/my_logfile.error.log', 'a')
```

I am getting something similar to this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_awesome_file.py", line 50, in <module>
    revision = session.Query()
AttributeError: 'Awesome' object has no attribute 'SomeSortOfAttribute'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_awesome_file.py", line 50, in <module>
    revision = session.Query()
AttributeError: 'Awesome' object has no attribute 'SomeSortOfAttribute'
```

It's two errors here (well, same error logged twice). I'd like to have if formatted a bit nicer (i.e. additional newline in between errors), and add a datetime if possible. Can I do it using this method of error logging?

Comment: Could you provide more detail than *"I was having trouble"*? Have you read [the `logging` documentation/how-tos](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html)? You can control the formatting with [`Formatter` objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#formatter-objects).

Comment: Edited the question removing possibly excessive info. I hope there's no need to close it now?

Comment: Now the answer is just *"no"*; if you simply redirect `stderr` to file, you get the default traceback. If you want more control over where the errors go and what the look like, `logging` is the way to go.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Cool thanks, I am happy you're not going to close it anymore so I may get a proper answer in time. Like they say, if you can't help at least don't hurt.Thanks!

Comment: *"if you can't help at least don't hurt"*? Get some perspective - it was one close vote, on a bad question, which you have now improved; *that is what is supposed to happen*. And I don't know what *"proper answer"* you're expecting: **no, you can't control the format if you use *"this method of error logging"***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little bit of reading Python manuals, it seems the solution is rather easy - instead of directly using file open() as a stream for stderr, I just have to use a custom stream. It's so painfully obvious it puzzles me why I didn't come up with it immediately. Well, it was Friday evening after all.

A very basic version would be:

```
import time

class LogStream(object):

    def write(self, text):
        f = open('py/log/my.custom.error.log', 'a')
        f.write(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S ") + text + "\r\n")
        f.close()
```

And then

```
sys.stderr = LogStream()
```

Result:

```
12:03:05 Traceback (most recent call last):

12:03:05   File "py/stuff.py", line 38, in <module>

12:03:05     
12:03:05 raise Exception("just some test")

12:03:05 Exception
12:03:05 : 
12:03:05 just some test
12:03:05
```

I might want to customize it a bit more but it's good enough already.